# How do you cancel an NSArray sort that is in progress?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` offer  multiple ways to sort them using the `sortedArrayUsing...` and `sortUsing...` methods respectively, however none of those methods appear to offer a way to terminate a sort after it has been started.

For relatively small arrays, or when the comparison logic is trivial, this is probably not a big deal, but with larger arrays or when the comparison logic is not trivial, I would like to be able to cancel a sort already in process.

**Trivial Use Case Example**

Sorting a set of results that match based on a user's fuzzy search string. As the user types in the search field, results are fetched on a background thread and sorted before being presented to the user. If the fetch-and-sort operation is not completed before the user changes the search string, then it should be cancelled and a new fetch-and-sort operation started. The problem is that if the fetch-and-sort operation has already reached the sorting stage and called one of the `NSArray` sort methods above, then there's no way to cancel it. Instead, the next fetch-and-sort operation is left waiting for the now stale sort operation to complete.

So far, I've come up with two possible solutions but neither seems all that elegant.

**Attempted Solution #1**

Allow newer fetch-and-sort operations to start before any stale fetch-and-sort operations are finished. I just keep track of which is the latest operation using some internal state and as the operations complete, if they aren't the primary operation, then their results are discarded.

This works, but it can quickly result in multiple outstanding sorting operations all running concurrently, whether they need to be or not. This can be somewhat mitigated by throttling the maximum number of concurrent operations, but then I'm just adding an arbitrary limit. Pending, stale operations can be cancelled before they get executed, but I'm still left with situations where sorting work is being done when it doesn't need to be.

**Attempted Solution #2**

Roll my own quick sort or merge sort implementation and add an `isCancelled` flag to those routines so that they can quickly unwind and terminate. This is working, and working fairly well, but when the sorting operation doesn't need to be cancelled, the run time is about 15-20% slower than using one of the `NSArray` methods. Part of this, I imagine, is the overhead of calling methods like `objectAtIndex` and `exchangeObjectAtIndex` which I *assume* the internal sorting routines can bypass depending on how the NSArray is internally storing the objects in question.

It also feels *wrong* to be rolling my own sorting implementations in 2015 against something like `AppKit` and `NSArray`.

**Semi-Attempted Solutions**

- Keeping a previously sorted array around and re-using that for filtering: This doesn't really work for what I'm trying to do so for sake of discussion, assume that the array I have to sort on is always unsorted and has no relationship to the previously sorted array.
- Moving away from `NSArray` and back to C-style arrays: This works pretty well and the performance is quite good, but I'm left playing a bunch of games with `ARC` and the complexity of the overall implementatiion is significantly higher because at the end of the day, I'm always dealing with `NSObjects`. There's also a non-zero cost of going back and worth between `NSArray` and C-style arrays.

**Summary**

So, all of that to get back to the original question: "How do you cancel an in-progress `NSArray` sorting method?"

**Tech Note**

For those that are curious why this is a problem to begin with, I'm attempting to sort somewhere between 500,000 to 1,000,000 strings using compare methods like `localizedStandardCompare`, which is dramatically slower than just a straight `NSString` compare. The runtime difference between the various `sortUsing...` methods is relatively insignificant when compared to the total time to sort.

Comment: Out of topic: If you have that big array with 1.000.000 objects in it and if you want to sort it, don't use nsarray, use ccarray https://github.com/manucorporat/CCArray it is much more faster than nsarray

Comment: I think writing your own version is the only way.  In order to improve performance perhaps you could implement it within a category and gain some advantage by accessing the class variables (not the cleanest OO solution as the variables are undocumented).

Comment: I don't think is it possible, NSObject provides a method to cancel requests make with a delay. Furthermore since sorting methods are run synchronously, you can call a cancel operation only once they have finished.
In my opinion you should create you own implementation using enumeration block or wrap in NSOperation.

Comment: Sort in chunks and then merge.  You can cancel between operations.

Answer (score 2):

Starting where you end:

> So, all of that to get back to the original question: "How do you cancel an in-progress NSArray sorting method?"

You don't. Cancellation isn't supported and anything you come up with is bound to be fragile.

So back to what you've done:

> Roll my own quick sort or merge sort implementation and add an isCancelled flag to those routines so that they can quickly unwind and terminate. This is working, and working fairly well, but when the sorting operation doesn't need to be cancelled, the run time is about 15-20% slower than using one of the NSArray methods.

This is the way to go in this case, you just need to work on that slowdown...

You might be right, part of the slowdown might be the need to call methods for indexing and exchanging elements. Have you tried caching C function pointers to the common methods you require? If at the start of a sort you obtain direct C function pointers to `objectAtIndex:` et al. using the Objective-C runtime function `class_getMethodImplementation()` you can replace all the calls to method lookup with simple indirection.

If such manipulations fail then maybe look at C arrays again. As `NSArray` is toll-free bridged to `CFArrayRef` you can use `CFArrayGetValues` to copy out the elements into a `malloc`'ed C array, sort that, and then use `CFArrayCreate` to get back to a `NSArray`. Provided you are careful and not mutating the array you are sorting, as the elements will be in the original array they will already be retained and creating the new array will retain them once more, you can probably handle memory management by doing nothing. Sorting the C-array will be faster, but extraction and creation are going to be O(N) operations on top of the sort.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

After several days of testing, I've opted to go with a custom, in-place merge sort implementation that accepts a boolean flag to trigger a cancellation.

A few follow-up points for those interested:

- The raw performance of my merge sort implementation still lags somewhat behind the raw performance of the `NSArray sortUsingComparator` method. Instruments indicates that `NSArray` is using a merge sort as well, so I suspect the performance difference can be attributed to a more tuned implementation by Apple than I came up with and the ability to directly access `NSArray's` internals. `NSArray's` implementation took about 28 seconds to sort 1,000,000 strings using `localizedStandardCompare` as compared to 31.5 seconds for mine. (MacBook Air 2013)
- Converting an `NSMutableArray` to a C-array of objects did not yield enough of a performance improvement to warrant the added complexity. The sort time was only reduced by between 0.5 - 1.0 second. Nice to have, but still dwarfed by the time spent in `localizedStandardCompare`. For input arrays of much smaller sizes (100,000), the speed difference was almost negligible. This surprised me, but Instruments is showing that all of the "overhead" in using an `NSMutableArray` is mostly noise when compared to the sort operation itself.
- Parallelizing the merge function and farming out the tasks via `GCD` yielded a noticeable improvement of between 6.0 - 7.0 seconds, reducing the total time to sort to less than what `NSArray sortUsingComparator` was taking. Tuning the job count and stride length based on input array size could offer even more improvements (albeit minor ones at this stage).

Ultimately, a parallelized and cancelable implementation is proving to offer the best user experience for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think common way to handle the problem you are mentioning, is not to cancel sorting, but to add a delay before fetch/sort operation is made.

Users usually type in short bursts. So add a delay of x seconds(e.g. 0.5s) before fetch and sort will actually begin.

Example:

1. User types 'a'.
2. Start a x second timer.
3. Before timer expires user types 'b'
4. Invalidate old timer and start a new one with x seconds.
5. Timer expires, start fetch and sort operation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but adding a delay doesn't help all that much if the sort itself takes significantly longer than the arbitrarily chosen delay. The number of outstanding operations will be reduced, but outstanding operations will still exist. I also think that type-ahead-matching on a low latency data source (local computer) should be as fast as possible and adding arbitrary delays just slows down the user experience. For high latency data sources it might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own sorting algorithm (which check for cancelation), you can implement your own comparator, which can check the cancelation condition, and throw an exception to interrupt the NSArray sortUsing...
The call to NSArray sortUsing.. should be enclosed in a try/catch group

```
- (void) testInterruptSort
{
    NSArray *a = @[@"beta", @"alpha", @"omega", @"foo", @"bar"];
     NSArray *sorted;
    BOOL interrupted = NO;
    NSString * const myException = @"User";
    @try {
         int __block n = 0;
        sorted = [a sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
            if (/* cancel condition*/ (1) && (n>5)) {
                n++;
                NSException *e = [NSException exceptionWithName:myException reason:@"interrupted" userInfo:nil];
                [e raise];
            }
             return [s1 localizedStandardCompare:s2];
        }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // should check if this is the "User" exception
        // see       https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html
        interrupted = YES;
    }
    @finally {
    }
    NSLog(@"interrupted: %@, result = %@\n", interrupted ? @"YES":@"NO", sorted);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately ARC does not guarantee to handle memory management correctly across an exception, and you have no control over what `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` might be doing involving dynamic memory between your call to it and its call to your comparator. So nice idea, but Objective-C bites you :-( (Of course ARC could have theoretically been written to handle exceptions, this is simply a design decision based on exceptions only being recommended for use for program terminating situations in Objective-C.)

Comment: yes, pretty annoying... -fobjc-arc-exceptions option is said to enable ARC exception support, with a performance penalty - but i never tried it. It may not work here, though (as stacks to be unwind contains NSArray code, which we can't assume to be compiled with -fobjc-arc-exceptions)..